# Cmake create Xcode project to build llvm/clang error

Tags: xcode, cmake, clang, llvm

I've extracted llvm/clang/compiler-rt sources from official repos, but i was unable to create Xcode project:

```
MBA-Anton:llvm-34-xcode-build asmirnov$ cmake -G Xcode ../llvm_34
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 5.1.0
-- Looking for C++ include cxxabi.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for C++ include cxxabi.h - not found
-- Looking for dirent.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for dirent.h - not found
-- Looking for dlfcn.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for dlfcn.h - not found
-- Looking for errno.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for errno.h - not found
-- Looking for execinfo.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for execinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for fcntl.h - not found
-- Looking for inttypes.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for inttypes.h - not found
-- Looking for limits.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for limits.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for malloc/malloc.h - not found
-- Looking for ndir.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for pthread.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Looking for sanitizer/msan_interface.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sanitizer/msan_interface.h - not found
-- Looking for signal.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for signal.h - not found
-- Looking for stdint.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for stdint.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/dir.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/dir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/ioctl.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/mman.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/mman.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/ndir.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/param.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/param.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/resource.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/resource.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/stat.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/stat.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/time.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/time.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/uio.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/uio.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/wait.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for sys/wait.h - not found
-- Looking for termios.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for termios.h - not found
-- Looking for unistd.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for unistd.h - not found
-- Looking for utime.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for utime.h - not found
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for valgrind/valgrind.h - not found
-- Looking for zlib.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for zlib.h - not found
-- Looking for fenv.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for fenv.h - not found
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for FE_ALL_EXCEPT - not found
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for FE_INEXACT - not found
-- Looking for mach/mach.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for mach/mach.h - not found
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for mach-o/dyld.h - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in c
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for pthread_create in c - not found
-- Looking for dlopen in dl
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for dlopen in dl - not found
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for clock_gettime in rt - not found
-- Looking for compress2 in z
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for compress2 in z - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in tinfo
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for setupterm in tinfo - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in terminfo
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for setupterm in terminfo - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in curses
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for setupterm in curses - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in ncurses
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for setupterm in ncurses - not found
-- Looking for setupterm in ncursesw
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


...


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for strtoll - not found
-- Looking for strtoq
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for strtoq - not found
-- Looking for strerror
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for strerror - not found
-- Looking for strerror_r
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for strerror_r - not found
-- Looking for strerror_s
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for strerror_s - not found
-- Looking for setenv
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for setenv - not found
-- Looking for __GLIBC__
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for __GLIBC__ - not found
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_INT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_UINT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_U_INT64_T - Failed
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test LLVM_HAS_ATOMICS - Failed
-- Warning: LLVM will be built thread-unsafe because atomic builtins are missing
-- Could NOT find LibXml2 (missing:  LIBXML2_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test SUPPORTS_NO_VARIADIC_MACROS_FLAG - Failed
-- Target triple: x86_64-apple-darwin13.2.0
-- Native target architecture is X86
-- Looking for _strtoi64
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Looking for _strtoi64 - not found
-- Threads disabled.
-- Doxygen disabled.
CMake Warning at cmake/modules/HandleLLVMOptions.cmake:109 (message):
  -fPIC not supported with Xcode.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:272 (include)


-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_MISSING_FIELD_INITIALIZERS_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test C_SUPPORTS_COVERED_SWITCH_DEFAULT_FLAG - Failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG
CMake Error at /usr/local/Cellar/cmake/2.8.11.1/share/cmake/Modules/CMakeCXXInformation.cmake:37 (get_filename_component):
  get_filename_component called with incorrect number of arguments
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:3 (PROJECT)


CMake Error: Internal CMake error, TryCompile configure of cmake failed
-- Performing Test CXX_SUPPORTS_NON_VIRTUAL_DTOR_FLAG - Failed
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.5") 
-- Constructing LLVMBuild project information
-- Targeting AArch64
-- Targeting ARM
-- Targeting CppBackend
-- Targeting Hexagon
-- Targeting Mips
-- Targeting MSP430
-- Targeting NVPTX
-- Targeting PowerPC
-- Targeting R600
-- Targeting Sparc
-- Targeting SystemZ
-- Targeting X86
-- Targeting XCore
CMake Error at projects/compiler-rt/CMakeLists.txt:52 (message):
  Please use architecture with 4 or 8 byte pointers.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
MBA-Anton:llvm-34-xcode-build asmirnov$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cmake 2.8.11 bug. Works in cmake 2.8.12.12